# Using Nest D3 Library? Making JSON with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am trying to make JSON for a sunwheel diagram in D3.  However my data is not in the right format.  I wrote a little javascript snippet to make it into the correct JSON format.  However, I am having some trouble as some of the names refer to the same parent.  I was wondering how to fix the naming problem, as I want to keep each name there? I included a fiddle with comments, as this may be confusing.

http://jsfiddle.net/dbffL7et/1/

tldr: Is there a way to check multiple parents to see if it exists?

```
 // create a name: node map
 var dataMap = data.reduce(function (map, node) {
     map[node.name] = node;
     return map;
     }, {});

   // create the tree array
   var tree = [];
   data.forEach(function (node) {
   // add to parent
var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
if (parent) {
    // create child array if it doesn't exist
    (parent.children || (parent.children = [])) //something to change here??
    // add node to child array
    .push(node);
} else {
    // parent is null or missing
    tree.push(node);
}
});
```